# In Perl, why does 100*18.35 not compare equal to 1835?

Tags: perl, floating-point, floating-point-comparison

When I run the following Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -e 'print "Oh no!\n" unless 1835 == 100*18.35'
```

I get

```
Oh no!
```

Why is that?

Comment: You missed code formatting. :(

Comment: @toreau I've improved formatting

Comment: Using a pencil and paper write down the *decimal* representation of 1/3rd. Multiply it by 3.  Tell us the answer.  If you wrote down 0.3333 your answer will be 0.9999. In programming a floating point number is often stored using a binary representation, much like this example just used of representing 1/3rd as 0.3333. That's what you missed.

Comment: You missed several things, including, but not limited to the fact that your question is not about string comparisons at all, but you gave your post a misleading title. And, the fact that you added weird complications to make the problem statement as opaque as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're missing is an old computer science problem - floating point conversion.

You see, you cannot *precisely* represent '0.35' as a floating point number since it's a periodic number in binary.

So if you add:

```
my $new = $a->{a} - $b;
print $new;
```

You'll get:

```
2.27373675443232e-013
```

`$a->{a}` *is* very slightly more than `$b` and thus the test *is* correct.

You can see this at work if you:

```
my $new_val = 18.35 - 18;
print $new_val;
```

Whilst we're at it though - don't use `$a` or `$b` - they're reserved for `sort`. And single letter var names aren't good style anyway.

Also `my $a = {};` is redundant - there's no need to initialise an empty hash-reference like that.

To do what you want, then you either need to compare 'like types' or cast explicitly to integer:

```
$a->{a} = int(18.35 * 100);
```

Comment: Using `int` always rounds down, which isn't always correct. You need to round to nearest.